# "Read-only filesystem" on NFS share, permissions, mounts and exports file seem ok

Tags: networking, permissions, filesystems, nfs

I am sharing `/share/global/usr/share` from a server to `/usr/share` on a client via NFS. When the client writes into it I get "Read-only filesystem" error.

## Server

Filesystem permissions ok:

```
$> ls -la /share/global/usr/
drwxrwxrwx 2 nobody nogroup 4096 Dec  6 14:37 share
```

Exports are rw for client IP `192.168.101.250`, other internal IPs are ro.

```
$> grep usr /etc/exports
/share/global/usr/share 192.168.0.0/16(ro,subtree_check,all_squash) 192.168.101.250(rw,subtree_check,all_squash)
```

Server can write here:

```
$> echo HELLO > /share/global/usr/share/REMOVEME && chmod 666 /share/global/usr/share/REMOVEME && echo ok
ok
```

## Client

IP address matches (static):

```
$> ip addr | grep inet
inet 192.168.101.250/24 brd 192.168.101.255 scope global enp0s8
```

fstab specifies rw:

```
$> grep usr /etc/fstab
192.168.101.254:/share/global/usr/share /usr/share nfs rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=3,intr,rw
```

and it's mounted rw:

```
$> mount | grep usr
192.168.101.254:/share/global/usr/share on /usr/share type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4.0,rsize=8192,wsize=8192,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=3,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=192.168.101.250,local_lock=none,addr=192.168.101.254)
```

Read is ok:

```
$> ls -al /usr/share/REMOVEME
-rw-rw-rw-. 1 nfsnobody nfsnobody 7 Dec  6 15:14 /usr/share/REMOVEME
```

## Problem

On client:

```
$> sudo -i
$> echo foo > /usr/share/REMOVEME
-bash: /usr/share/REMOVEME: Permission denied
```

I also can't create new files here.

Everything in the configuration looks okay to me. Why can't I write to the shared directory on the client?

Server is Ubuntu 16.04, client is CentOS 7.

Comment: SElinux in play here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`/etc/exports` wants the specific IP addresses to appear first, IP ranges after.

i.e.

```
/share/global/usr/share 192.168.101.250(rw,subtree_check,all_squash) 192.168.0.0/16(ro,subtree_check,all_squash)
```

Comment: I wonder if the ordering in your example is important because your IP range has a more restrictive permission granted than the single host.  I think if the IP range was a different subnet from your single host, it could still be listed first.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to get the error message when writing to the **root** of the NFS mount on the client. I had a similar issue and to me it seems that NFS server shows the all "disks" as "virtual devices" in the root, which is not really any directory on the server, but a "virtual listing" provided by the NFS server, resulting in "Read-only file system" -error message. Depending on your configuration, you might get the error message when writing to the root of the shared volume.

However, if you have a sub-directory on a shared disk, and try to write there, it works fine.

Demonstration on the client:

```
 root@dunharg:/mnt/share# touch write-test
 touch: cannot touch 'write-test': Read-only file system
 root@dunharg:/mnt/share# ls
 backup  hdd  nvme  ssd
 root@dunharg:/mnt/share# cd sdd
 root@dunharg:/mnt/share/sdd# ls
 home  share
 root@dunharg:/mnt/share/sdd# touch write-test
 touch: cannot touch 'write-test': Read-only file system
 root@dunharg:/mnt/share/sdd# cd share
 root@dunharg:/mnt/share/sdd/share# touch write-test
 ok
```